# pell's equation converge

Tags: algebraic-topology, pell-type-equations

Explain Why pell's equation $x_n+ny_n=1$, $(x_n/y_n)^2$ is coverge to n as n increase

For example, n=11 the answer $(x_n/y_n)^2$ is very close to 11 when n increase.

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: if you are going to call the fixed coefficient $n,$ you should change the index. Other errors as well. Correct: $$ x_j^2 - n y_j^2 = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{P}_d(\mathbb{Z})^+$ be the set of the positive integer solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-dy^2=1$, we have that, if $(a,b)\in\mathcal{P}_d(\mathbb{Z})^+$, then, $a/b$ is a convergent of $\sqrt d$, when you square $a/b$ you are getting ridiculously good rational approximations of $d$, remember convergents give you the "best" rational approximations